# operator << overload c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stream

how can i overload "<<" operator (for cout) so i could do "cout" to a class k

Comment: this "cout<<k" (k is a class)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The canonical implementation of the output operator for any type `T` is this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
  os << obj.get_data1() << get_data2();
  return os;
}
```

Note that output stream operators commonly are not member functions. (That's because for binary operators to be member functions they have to be members of their left-hand argument's type. That's a stream, however, and not your own type. There is the exception of a few overloads of `operator<<()` for some built-ins, which are members of the output stream class.)
Therefor, if not all data of `T` is publicly accessible, this operator has to be a friend of `T`

```
class T {
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&);
  // ... 
};
```

or the operator calls a public function which does the streaming:

```
class T {
public:
  void write_to_stream(std::ostream&);
  // ... 
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
  obj.write_to_stream(os);
  return os;
}
```

The advantage of the latter is that the `write_to_stream()` member function can be `virtual` (and pure), allowing polymorphic classes to be streamed.

If you want to be fancy and support all kinds of streams, you'd have to templatize that:

```
template< typename TCh, typename TTr >
std::basic_ostream<TCh,TTr>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<TCh,TTr>& os, const T& obj)
{
  os << obj.get_data1() << get_data2();
  return os;
}
```

(Templates, however, don't work with virtual functions.)

Comment: Where `T` is the type of the object `k` that you want to print.

Comment: wow! waht is "T" (in the "const T& obj"). and how can i add it to my class k?

Comment: Should it not be templated to be character-type agnostic? If I wanted to use wcout with this operator, not much would happen.

Comment: the way I learned it you create a write(std::ostream&) memberfunction instead of making the operator<< a friend. (I think its better for inheritance make write virtual and you can overwrite it). The rest is great

Comment: @josefx: That's an excellent point, thank you. I've done that in the past, too, I just forgot to mention it. I'll add it to the answer.