# Is it possible, in any way, to provide a stream-operator as inline in a class (i.e. non-friend)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

First of all, I'd like to point out that I did read through the solution [{provided here}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062002/857994) which states:

> Note that output stream operators commonly are not member functions. (That's because for binary operators to be member functions they have to be members of their left-hand argument's type. That's a stream, however, and not your own type. There is the exception of a few overloads of operator<<() for some built-ins, which are members of the output stream class.)

Now, here's my problem. I was removing a library from a large application. The library was supposed to have any useful functionality from it condensed into a header file.

One of the classes in this header file needs to have a stream << operator overload.  I cannot figure out how to do this without a friend function, and if I use a friend function I cannot do it all in a header because I'll get multiple definition errors.

So, is there any trick - maybe some play with functors, wrappers, or whatever, that will allow me to write a definition for the operator overload for << in my class to avoid this issue?

Comment: "inline in a class" and "non-friend" are orthogonal -- it can be both inline in a class and friend.

Comment: @ildjarn you're right - I fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class SomeClass
{
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, SomeClass const& sc)
    {
        // impl
        return os;
    }
};
```

Function definitions provided inline inside of the class definition are implicitly marked `inline` and consequently will not cause multiple-definition linker errors.

Alternatively, you can provide the definition out-of-line and explicitly mark it `inline`, again avoiding multiple-definition linker errors:

```
class SomeClass
{
    // unnecessary if operator<< doesn't need access to non-public members
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, SomeClass const&);
};

inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, SomeClass const& sc)
{
    // impl
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I use a friend function I cannot do it all in a header because I'll
>   get multiple definition errors.

Mark the friend function inline, then you won't get multiple definition errors.

Answer (score 1):

No, the semantics of how operator overloading works would prevent you from doing this.

But there's nothing that says a friend function can't also be (qualified as) inline, in which case you don't have to worry about multiple definitions: The compiler does.

I would say one usual method to implement streaming is with a public (possibly virtual) print function that takes a stream& and then call that from a non-member, non-friend `operator<<`, which could easily be inlined in your header.

Comment: This was probably the answer I needed - let me give it a try quick and come back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a base class with something like `void streamout(std::ostream& out)` virtual member function and a friend (if you have to keep this private, though I can't come up with a reason why) operator which is not member. Then for all derived classes you'd have to implement a member function, which is what you seem to want.